# Why the Following? $|\sqrt{n^2-7}-n| = \frac{7}{|\sqrt{n^2-7}+n|} \leq \frac{7}{|n|}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can someone please explain to me why this following algebraic transition is true?

> $$\left| \sqrt { n^{ 2 }-7 } -n \right| =\frac { 7 }{ \left| \sqrt { n^{ 2 }-7 } +n \right|  } \leq \frac { 7 }{ \left| n \right|  } $$

Edit: whomever down-voted my post, do you mind telling me why you did so?

Comment: Oh, you center-aligned the math text, and made the text in the fraction bigger.
How did you do it? (I'm not very experienced in TeX).

Comment: ``$$\x=y$$`` vs. ``$x=y$`` triggers display style. I.e., centering, bigger fractions, and some additional eye-candy that takes more space.

Comment: Oh, I did not know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply both numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{n^2-7}+n$ and use the identity $(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2$.

This is a standard trick/technique of *multiplying by the conjugate.*

Comment: Oh, right. I did such things in complex numbers when I studied them in high school. I didn't notice it.

In multiplying by the conjugate, is the multiplication only on the form $(a\pm b)$?

So we get $(a \pm b) = (a \mp b)$

Comment: With complex numbers, it's the complex conjugate, $a+ib$ vs. $a-ib$. Here, it is "simply" with real numbers, something of the form $a+\sqrt{b}$ vs. $a-\sqrt{b}$ to somehow make the square roots "disappear."

Comment: Oh, okay. I've never seen this technique in real numbers.

Thanks for the information! :)

By the way, do you know is it taught in the US/some European countries in pre-calculus algebra? Where did you learn it from?

Comment: Some exercises in middle and high school, IIRC. (France)

Comment: Okay, thanks for the information. :)

Answer (score 1):

$$\left| \sqrt { n^{ 2 }-7 } -n \right| =\left| \frac { \left( \sqrt { n^{ 2 }-7 } -n \right) \left( \sqrt { n^{ 2 }-7 } +n \right)  }{ \sqrt { n^{ 2 }-7 } +n }  \right| =\left| \frac { n^{ 2 }-7-{ n }^{ 2 } }{ \sqrt { n^{ 2 }-7 } +n }  \right| =\\=\frac { 7 }{ \left| \sqrt { n^{ 2 }-7 } +n \right|  } \leq \frac { 7 }{ \left| n \right|  } $$

Comment: Great, thank you very much. :)

Comment: Do you mind explaining me/proving the 2nd inequality, please?

Answer (score 0):

The first equality comes from 
$$(\sqrt{n^2-7}-n)(\sqrt{n^2-7}+n)=(n^2-7)-n^2=-7.$$

The second inequality comes from $\sqrt{n^2-7}+n\ge n$.